# let array behavior in Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am befuddled by the current array behavior in Swift 2.1. I have read the docs and many posts (which could be out-of-date) and am no closer to understanding.

Here's my code for separating a deck of cards into wildCards and non-wildcards:

```
    let wildCards : [Card] = []
    let nonWildCards : [NonJoker] = []
    Meld.sortAndSeparateWildCards(wildCardRank, cards: self.cards, nonWildCards: nonWildCards, wildCards: wildCards)
```

...

```
static func sortAndSeparateWildCards(wildCardRank : Rank, var cards : [Card], var nonWildCards : [NonJoker], var wildCards : [Card]) {
    //cards contains the list to be sorted
    if cards.isEmpty {return}
    nonWildCards.removeAll()
    wildCards.removeAll()
    for card in cards {
        if (card.isWildCard(wildCardRank)!) {wildCards.append(card)}
        else {nonWildCards.append(card as! NonJoker)}
    }
    cards = nonWildCards.sort(NonJoker.cardComparatorRankFirstDesc)
    cards += wildCards
}
```

What I don't understand:

1. Xcode *insists* that I should change wildCards and nonWildCards to `let` constants, even though I am mutating the arrays by adding values to them (many of the posts I have read say that `let` behavior prevents adding to or removing elements from an Array)
2. I originally had these arrays passed as inout variables, because I thought that Arrays were passed by value and not by reference (the docs suggest that they are treated this way; see the bottom of this page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)

EDIT: I thought the code was working, but I was confused. 
Corrected code, per the answer below, with the bad behavior that isEmpty returns nil.

```
    var wildCards : [Card] = []
    var nonWildCards : [NonJoker] = []
    Meld.sortAndSeparateWildCards(wildCardRank, cards: &self.cards, nonWildCards: &nonWildCards, wildCards: &wildCards)
```

...

```
static func sortAndSeparateWildCards(wildCardRank : Rank, inout cards : [Card], inout nonWildCards : [NonJoker], inout wildCards : [Card]) {
    //cards contains the list to be sorted
    if cards.isEmpty {return}
    nonWildCards.removeAll()
    wildCards.removeAll()
    for card in cards {
        if (card.isWildCard(wildCardRank)!) {wildCards.append(card)}
        else {nonWildCards.append(card as! NonJoker)}
    }
    cards = nonWildCards.sort(NonJoker.cardComparatorRankFirstDesc)
    cards += wildCards
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are structs in Swift. In the way you've done it, the changes are not persisted out of the method. If you want to alter them in a function, you need to mark them as var in the declaration, and pass their pointer when calling the function. So something like this:

```
var wildCards = [Card]()
var nonWildCards = [NonJoker]()
static func sortAndSeparateWildCards(wildCardRank : Rank, inout cards : [Card], inout nonWildCards : [NonJoker], inout wildCards : [Card]) {}
Meld.sortAndSeparateWildCards(wildCardRank, cards: &self.cards, nonWildCards: &nonWildCards, wildCards: &wildCards)
```

Comment: Ok, so I changed my code accordingly. Now before the call to sortAndSeparate self.cards has 8 values. inside sortAndSeparate... the debugger shows it as an "lvalue" and it's empty (so the function returns immediately). Help!

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the same variable, which has 8 values, as the 'cards' parameter?

Comment: Yes. I just found the problem: with the inout change (edited code above), the cards.isEmpty returns nil. By commenting out this check, everything is working just fine. Does this qualify as a bug?

Comment: I don't see how cards.isEmpty can return nil, since cards is not declared as optional. Its quite unlikely (although not impossible) for Swift to have bug. If you like, provide more of the code you're using.

Comment: .isEmpty is implemented in this way when I click through:

     extension CollectionType {
    /// Returns `true` iff `self` is empty.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(1)
    public var isEmpty: Bool { get }`

Comment: When I replace `cards.isEmpty` with `cards.count == 0` the test passes and everything proceeds smoothly. I have always assumed these were equivalent.

Comment: @Opus1217 and they are! var arr:[Int] = []; arr.isEmpty // true; arr.count == 0 // true

Comment: You have to scroll back through my comments - in the debugger, isEmpty was returning true and cards.count==0 was false. Anyway, I'm accepting the answer to my original question, and I'll try to track down what's going on with isEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

You were right when assuming that arrays were being passed by value and not by reference. In Swift, arrays are value types - they are structs - which means that if you want to modify their contents, you need to declare them as `var`.

Now `var` has a broader meaning, and if it's applied to function arguments, it allows you to mutate those arguments within the function. However, keep in mind that you are mutating a copy of the array that was passed as argument.

So, in order for the changes that you apply to an array within a function be visible to the caller of that function, you need to declare the parameters as `inout`, which passes them by reference instead of value.